# Save uploaded image to a directory and save a resized copy to a seperate directory

Tags: php, image, resize

```
<?php


    $images = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"];
    $new_images = "small_".$_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
    $target = "large/".$new_images;

    $width=314; //*** Fix Width & Heigh (Autu caculate) ***//
    $size=GetimageSize($images);
    $height=round($width*$size[1]/$size[0]);
    $images_orig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($images);
    $photoX = ImagesX($images_orig);
    $photoY = ImagesY($images_orig);
    $images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
    ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width+1, 

 $height+1, $photoX, $photoY);
    ImageJPEG($images_fin,"uploads/".$new_images);
    ImageJPEG($images_orig,"large/".$new_images);
    ImageDestroy($images_orig);
    ImageDestroy($images_fin);


 ?>
```

I've been working at this for hours. I want the original image to be stored to the directory "large" and the resized image to store to "uploads" but the large won't store. The resized image stores just fine. What am I doing wrong? I've tried it a dozen different ways and this is where I gave up.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing imagejpeg on the original. That recompresses it and you lose quality. You should be using `move_uploaded_file()` instead, so the REAL original file will get saved.

Comment: @alok i didn't receive any errors with any of the attemps i tried. they just simply didn't store to the directory.

Comment: @MarcB i tried using move_uploaded_file() also, and that didn't work.

so my code was:

    `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"],
      "large/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);`

Comment: that'd be a HIDEOUS security vulnerability. `['name']` can contain pathing information, and that code would allow a malicious user to scribble a file ANYWHERE they want to on your server.

Comment: @MarcB would it still be dangerous if i checked if the file type was an image before uploading it? i considered doing that but i'm not sure if there would still be a malicious way around it

Comment: doesn't matter. you're using user-provided data in a dangerous manner. You should NOT be using THEIR filename. generate one yourself.

Comment: @MarcB ok, i've set it to use my own file name. thanks! another question, i'm uploading the photos in the directory root/admin/add-photo and i want it to upload to root/assets/pixels. how would i do that? i tried making the file path /assets/pixels/ but that isn't working and i tried `mysite.com/assets/pixels` and that isn't working either

Comment: m_u_f() works at the filesystem level. you need to use paths appropriate for your server's filesystem layout. Totally IGNORE any "virtual" directories, document roots, etc... created by your website. PHP has no knowledge of such things. it only sees the filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

So I know this is old, But here is my answer using your code... if you move the original file first to a directory. You can use that file to to re-size and then store where you want.

The $year, $renamefiledash and $ChangeSecond vars come from my own Form. You can just name the file what you like

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/downloads/media/'.$year.'/'.$renameFileDash.'.'.$changeSecond);


$images = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/downloads/media/'.$year.'/'.$renameFileDash.'.'.$changeSecond;

$width=618; //*** Fix Width & Heigh (Autu caculate) ***//
$size=GetimageSize($images);
$height=round($width*$size[1]/$size[0]);
$images_orig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($images);
$photoX = ImagesX($images_orig);
$photoY = ImagesY($images_orig);
$images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width+1, 
$height+1, $photoX, $photoY);
ImageJPEG($images_fin,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/media-archive/media-thumbs/'.$renameFileDash.'.'.$changeSecond);
ImageDestroy($images_orig);
ImageDestroy($images_fin);
```

Answer (score 0):

I find very usefull this php class:
[PHP image resize class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6331-PHP-Resize-GIF-JPEG-and-PNG-images.html)

A little example:

```
include("path/to/your/class/folder/resize_class.php"); 
$resizeObj = new resize('path/to/your/images/folder/name_of_image_recently_uploaded.jpg');
$resizeObj -> resizeImage(150, 100, 0);
$resizeObj -> saveImage('path/to/your/images/thumb/folder/name_of_image_recently_uploaded.jpg', 100);
```

Hope it helps!